# CSS prevent table cell from expanding vertically

Tags: html, css, resize, html-table, cell

I'm making a calendar using CSS and can't seem to get the table to fix it's layout when a cell has varying amounts of text within. Ideally I'd want the text to just be cut off when it goes beyond the size of the cell rather than expanding which is messing with the uniform look of the calendar. At the same time I need the table to be fullscreen and the top headers to be fixed as they are defined in the CSS. I managed to make this happen fine for the width of a cell using table-layout: fixed; but can't seem to get it working for the height. I've tried using `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden;` but can't seem to make it happen.

Any info would be very useful.

```css
.calendar_main{
 table-layout: fixed;
 position: absolute;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 font-size:20px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.calendar_main tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd), 
.calendar_main tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even)
{
 background-color: #f6f9eb;
}
.calendar_main td{
 border: 2px solid black;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.calendar_main th{
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: #A7C942;
 color: #ffffff;
 height:25px;
}

.icon{
 width:64px;
 height:64px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
#cal_title{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 height:64px;
 font-size:30px;
}
#cal_previous{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 height:64px;
}
#cal_next{
 text-align: right;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 height:64px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style_1.css'>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
 </head>
 <body>
  <center>
  <table class="calendar_main">
   <tr>
    <td colspan=2 id="cal_previous"><a href="index.php?section=calendar&month=3&year=2017"><img class="icon" src="icon_previous.png"></a></td>
    <td colspan=3 id="cal_title">April - 2017</td>
    <td colspan=2 id="cal_next"><a href="index.php?section=calendar&month=5&year=2017"><img class="icon" src="icon_next.png"></a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th><th>Sun</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1<br>Event1<br>Event2<br>Event3<br>Event4</td>
    <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5<br>Event1</td>
    <td>6<br>Event2</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>10<br>Event1</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12<br>Event1</td>
    <td>13<br>Event1</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21<br>Event1<br>Event2</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>24<br>Event1</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need the  text in the cells to support multiple lines. is there another way to do this after removing the <br>'s? Maybe a pre formated and using line breaks? or will this just cause the same problems? regarding the fixed height for the cells, would that mean I have to use javascript to adjust the height directly of each cell using a specific px value for each?

Comment: Setting height for td does not help. What i said about setting height, was the rule of using `overflow` at all, not this case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to limit the height of table cells. You can wrap the content of the table cell in a div and set a max-height for div:

```css
.calendar_main{
 table-layout: fixed;
 position: absolute;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 font-size:20px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.calendar_main td div{height: 9vh; overflow: hidden;}
.calendar_main tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd), 
.calendar_main tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even)
{
 background-color: #f6f9eb;
}
.calendar_main td{
 border: 2px solid black;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.calendar_main th{
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: #A7C942;
 color: #ffffff;
 height:25px;
}

.icon{
 width:64px;
 height:64px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
#cal_title{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 height:64px;
 font-size:30px;
}
#cal_previous{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 height:64px;
}
#cal_next{
 text-align: right;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 height:64px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style_1.css'>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
 </head>
 <body>
  <center>
  <table class="calendar_main">
   <tr>
    <td colspan=2 id="cal_previous"><a href="index.php?section=calendar&month=3&year=2017"><img class="icon" src="icon_previous.png"></a></td>
    <td colspan=3 id="cal_title">April - 2017</td>
    <td colspan=2 id="cal_next"><a href="index.php?section=calendar&month=5&year=2017"><img class="icon" src="icon_next.png"></a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th><th>Sun</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div>1<br>Event1<br>Event2<br>Event3<br>Event4</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5<br>Event1</div></td>
    <td><div>5<br>Event1</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><div>5<br>Event1</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5<br>Event1</div></td>
    <td><div>5<br>Event1</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5<br>Event1</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><div>5<br>Event1</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
    <td><div>5</div></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make max-height dynamic to the cell height?

Comment: As i mentioned `max-height` does not work for table cell or row. Why you don't set the max height directly for the div in table cell? It automatically limit its parent (table cell).

Comment: Because I need the whole calendar to be dynamic to the size of the browser window. If I'm setting specific values for a div within a cell then isn't it not going to work in different aspect ratios?

Comment: Not specific value. You can set dynamic `max-height`, but for div, not the table cell. for example `div{ max-height: 5vh}` set a max height for all of your divs ( and table cells) 5% of the height  of screen.

Comment: Thanks for your sample! However, it seems as the cell becomes higher the max-height isn't correctly adjusting. The larger it gets the larger the mask at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry if you want to change it, you need to put a div in all of your table cells and change the `11vh` to `10vh`. It is easy and i am sure you can do this.

Comment: Currently, there is the **single row** cells that make the height! In another way the single row cells (that has not wrapper div) has the largest height that make the height of row.

Comment: This isn't working. I don't understand how setting a div to 10% of the height of the screen will help here. Wouldn't that only work if there were 10 rows of cells? and none of the extra menu stuff at the top? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/24o9hx8d/)

Comment: **10% is nearly same as 10vh !!** No it isn't. When you have a `max-height` smaller than the height, It is the max height that is working. I tested the 100% for max-height and it changed back to your first sample.

Comment: See my updated code snippet. do not forger to use this for all screens, you must set dynamic height for all of the rows cells. (header cells ...)

Comment: Please do not forget to point the helpful answer with accept or upvote.

Comment: You said *The larger it gets the larger the mask at the bottom.* But it is not larger than the screen now.

Comment: I'm talking about each cell, the text is cut off the more you expand the window. I need the text to fully fill each cell before it's cut off regardless of the size of the window. They seem to be out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

As Farzin said, it's impossible to limit the height of a `table-cell` element.

However, you can create an inner container for the table cells, and set a `height` (not `max-height`) to make the cells all the same height.

An inner container also allows the *visual* content of the cell to be a different height, which can be useful at times.